# renaming binary files in multiple subdirectories using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I've been trying for quite some time now with no success to rename multiple files which are located among multiple subdirectories. Some background: the files are in binary format and contain seismic data starting in 2000. I've downloaded all the data and placed it in a directory "seren". The downloaded data is separated into different subdirectories labeled by date time, i.e. Event_2000_01_08_16_47_20. In each of these subdirectories there are multiple files of the format (or some variation of) CN.FRB..BHE.sac, some look like II.BORG.00.BHN.sac (essentially of the format is NETWORK.STATION..CHANNEL.sac).

I am trying to write a bash script that will loop through all of the Event* subdirectories, and rename the *.sac files as SKS.${NETWORK}.${STATION}.${CHANNEL}.SAC -- essentially removing that 00 part in the middle

so far my code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for all in ~/seren/Event*
do
cd "$all"
pwd
echo "ls | awk -F "." '{print $1}'"  ### this is me attempting to grab the network name to add onto the new file name
done
###### in place of the echo line above I have also tried:
network = $((ls | awk -F "." '}print $1}'))
```

Comment: Why *" ... using awk"*? There are standard ways of doing this kind of thing using `find` to execute either a shell-based `mv` scriptlet or a perl-based `prename` command.

Answer (score 1):

No `awk` used. Not sure if that was a requirement or not. Place this script in the same directory as the `Event_*` directories.

```
#!/bin/sh    
# Find *.sac files with 00 in the name and remove that part.

LIST=`find ./ -mindepth 2 -type f -name \*.00.\*.sac`

for f in $LIST
do
    dir=${f%/*}
    fName=${f##*/}
    # remove the file ext as well
    fName=${fName%.*}
    # remove the 00 from the file name
    nName=`echo $fName | sed 's/.00././'`
    # DEBUG MODE
    echo "f:[${f}] d:[${dir}] n:[SKS.${nName}.SAC]"
    # LIVE
    #mv -vf "${f}" "${dir}/SKS.${nName}.SAC"
done
```

Highly suggest you run this on a back-up /test group first :]